# Is there an option to only show item names in the content tree?

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to display only the item name(not display name)in the content tree. I know one way is to select `item key` in the application setting option in Sitecore, but I wanted to know if this can be achieved through any configuration setting or through the pipeline as I don't want to do the same procedure manually in each environment.

Answer (score 3):

This value is stored per-user in the user's registry.

You can edit the value from code like:

```
Sitecore.Shell.UserOptions.View.UseDisplayName = false;
```

Which in fact sets in in registry

```
Registry.SetBool("/Current_User/UserOptions.View.UseDisplayName", value);
```

If you want to set it permanently for all the users, you could use e.g. `LoggedInProcessor` - when **any** user logs in, change his value in registry.

How to achieve that? There is a similar question on SSE asking about using `Shared Layout` always which does pretty much the same what you need. It's answered by @Gatogordo here:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/4850/277

I won't copy the whole answer - you just need to use different key.