# Always open shared layout while using experience editor sitecore 10.1.1

Tags: experience-editor

We want to always open shared layout in experience editor for our authors. We are using `Sitecore 10.1.1`.

As we have Sitecore 10.1.1 with azure ad login integration so, solution provided in link does not help:

[Force shared layout in experience editor](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/force-shared-layout-in-experience-editor)

Sitecore stores the user selection of layout in registry key `EditAllVersions`, I tried the solution provided in link:

https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/05/09/manage-users-registry-settings-after-login/

to always set the key `EditAllVersions` to `on` each time user logins.

But my custom Processor is not getting called every time when I login to Sitecore so the value of registry key `("{ "/Current_User/Page Editor/Show/EditAllVersions", "on" }")` does not get updated. I am patching my processor `after: "Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CleanupUserProfile"` as mentioned in solution.

Any ideas what I am missing out here?

Comment: Where you added your patch file? Are you able to see the entry in showconfig?

Comment: Please, provide your patching config file

Comment: I included my patch file under include folder. I was able to see it in showconfig. The processor gets called but the behavior is not consistent. It is not getting called every time I  refresh or login again.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CleanupUserProfile, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" type="XXX.SetUserRegistry, XXX" />
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Comment: put some logs in your processor and check if it triggers every time. Probably, it can be related to the passed arguments. As I see from links that your provided - there is a if statement in the beginning of the processor

Comment: Yes, I did put logs at different places in processor. Also, included log at first statement before the if condition. It is not getting logged every time.

Comment: If the processor way doesn't work for you properly you can try to implement it through powershell script that will be fired every time when user logged in. It can be event better because you don't need to change the pipeline and can change everything "on fly"

Comment: Why is it that you want to always open the shared layout in experience editor?

Comment: @Marcel Gruber This is a business requirement. They want content authors to always start editing the shared layout while creating new items so they don't have to add renderings again for different language versions incase forget to select the correct layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this by writing a custom processor in the "GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor" pipeline.
This will be called every time a user opens Experience Editor mode.
In the processor I updated the registry key to show shared layout and also added a notification message for user if they open final layout.

Code of the processor:

```
public class SetExperienceEditorLayout : GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(GetPageEditorNotificationsArgs arguments)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(arguments, "arguments");
            bool editingSharedVersion = WebUtility.IsEditAllVersionsTicked();
            if (!editingSharedVersion)
            {
                arguments.Notifications.Add(new PageEditorNotification("You are editing the final layout"), PageEditorNotificationType.Warning));             
                Registry.SetString(Constants.RegistryKeys.EditAllVersions,
                          Constants.Registry.CheckboxTickedRegistryValue);
            }
        }
```

Config to patch the processor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="ExperienceEditor" name="ExperienceEditor">
        <pipelines>
          <getPageEditorNotifications>
            <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.GetPageEditorNotifications.LanguageAccessNotification, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor']" type="MyProject.Sitecore.Pipeline.SetExperienceEditorLayout, MyProject.Sitecore" />
          </getPageEditorNotifications>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn` processor is not triggering consistently, it may be due to the fact that the `CleanupUserProfile` processor is clearing the user context before your custom processor can run.

One way to ensure that your processor runs before the `CleanupUserProfile` processor is to patch your processor before it in the `CookieAuthentication` pipeline, like so:

```xml
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        <processor patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.CleanupUserProfile, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" type="Your.Namespace.Here.SetUserRegistry, Your.Assembly.Name" />
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This should ensure that your custom processor runs before the CleanupUserProfile processor and can set the registry key value consistently.

Comment: Tried patching my processor before the CleanupUserProfile, but still no luck.

Comment: @litikachib let me ask one more time. Is it firing processor if your will sign in with 'admin' user as not an Azure AD account? Does it happen only in case of Azure AD?

Comment: I tried with both users, Admin as well as with Azure AD integration. The behavior is not consistent. First time it works, then if I change the layout from shared to final, then after login again it is not resetting back to shared.

Answer (score 0):

I verified the code with my vanilla `Sitecore 10.1` version and used the same class as shown in the article you mentioned.

https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/05/09/manage-users-registry-settings-after-login/

Here is my config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CleanupUserProfile, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']" type="Mysite.Custom.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.SetUserRegistry, WebApplication1" />
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And I put the config in the following location

```
\wwwroot\<my-site-root>\App_Config\Include\zzz\Pipelines.UserRegistry.config
```

When I logged in to Sitecore, I was able to debug it and it set all the registry items of the user.

Finally, when I opened a page in the `experience editor` mode, It showed the `Shared Layout` to me.

[image]

Try adding your config in the same location that I used in the `App_Config\Include\zzz` and it should work.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sumit for your answer. Is it happening every time? I mean if you change your layout from shared to final and then logout and login again, then also the layout changes back to shared(as per custom logic, at login registry key is set again) or it remains final (as per your last preference)?

Comment: @litikachib every time you log in, it runs and when you change the layout from shared to final then it will remain the final. Next time when you log in again, it will set it to shared. Hope this helps. This is the same implementation that you are referring from the blog you shared.

Comment: Did you verify it with Azure AD Integration?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I achieved this but writing a custom processor in "GetPageEditorNotificationsProcessor" pipeline. This will be called every time user opens experience editor mode. In the processor I updated the registry key to show shared layout and also added a notification message for user if they open final layout.